# Bootstrap smooth scrolling script breaking everything else on page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I include the following script titled smoothScroll.js into my web page:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The smooth scrolling is the ONLY thing on my page which works, all my links break and my contact modal does not show up even my bootstrap image slider does not work anymore. Can someone please help me.

This button/link:

```
    <div class="learnMore">
      <ul id="insidepagenav">
        <li><a href="#about" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a></li>
      </ul>
```

should smooth scroll to this section:

```
    <section id="about">

    </section>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because for example carousel has links with `href=#carousel-example-generic` and when you click on carousel arrow or pagination your smooth scrolling script is executed instead of Bootstrap carousel.

You can change click event to something like this:

```
$('a[smooth-scroll]').click(function() {
  // Content
});
```

And add this attribute to your links:

```
<a href="#about" class="btn btn-default" smooth-scroll>
```